# Asymmetric RelativeLayout behavior in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

The following two layout files produce different results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <View
      android:id="@+id/box"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_box" />
    <View
      android:id="@+id/next_box"
      android:background="#0000ff"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <View
      android:id="@+id/box"
      android:background="#ff0000"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />
    <View
      android:id="@+id/next_box"
      android:background="#0000ff"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/box"
      />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Both layouts are trying to describe the same constraints. Namely, the red rectangle should touch the left edge of the parent, the blue rectangle should touch the right edge of the parent, and they should appear next to each other horizontally. The only difference is whether you specify the "next to" constraint on the red rectangle or the blue rectangle. I figured out the reason which has to do with the measure resolution order generated by forming a dependency graph of the constraints, but I only figured it out through reading RelativeLayout's source code, and I couldn't find any documentation / notes regarding this behavior. Since RelativeLayout must be a commonly used layout component, is there a more intuitive explanation for this behavior, or is there some part of documentation that I am missing?

Comment: You have set the `layout_width` attribute or the first `View` to 0. In the first case, `RelativeLayout` explicitly gives it the remaining width, as you have defined it's left and right alignments. In the second case there is no right alignment defined, so it is layout to the left with 0 width, and the other `View` takes all the available width as it is explicitly defined to be aligned with the right border of the first `View`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although both seem to describe the same constraints, they actually don't. The difference is that one says, red must sit next to blue, while the other says blue must sit next to red. One means that where ever red goes blue must follow, the other says, where ever blue goes red must follow, and they both want to go to different places.

In the first instance, red box depends on the blue box, so the blue box gets constructed first. The blue box has a width of 60dp, so a 60dp blue box is constructed first and aligned right. Then comes the red box, which has a constraint to sit next to the blue box. Width 0 is ignore because it needs to sit next to 60dp blue and align left.

In the second instance, blue box depends on the red box, so the red box gets constructed first. The red box says it wants 0dp and align left, so it can't be seen. Then comes the blue box which needs to sit next to invisible red and align right, thus occupying the entire space, its width ignored.

Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and as I said in the last paragraph, I know the difference but I don't think it has been documented anywhere in the Android documentation, which can be quite confusing. Is this just silently understood among the Android community?

Comment: @dementrock: What's to document? The constraints are behaving exactly as defined, and in the only way it can make sense.

Comment: I think there could never be enough documentation for Android and its quirks. I had a quick look through the RelativeLayout documentation just then and found it to be a bit too brief. It would be good if there was more you could read up on. For me, using RelativeLayout is a bit of trial and error, and using your intuition to determine why it's behaving the way it is.

Comment: @corsair992 The problem is that what RelativeLayout is doing is NOT jointly solving a constraint-satisfaction problem. Instead, it is constructing a dependency graph based on the specified constraints, and resolving the positions and sizes of each view in an order based on those dependencies. It requires a different mind set as a developer since you don't just need to come up with the _set_ of constraints, but also a specific _order_ to specify those constraints. That's why I think this behavior really needs to be documented officially, or at least explained in the community somewhere.

Comment: @dementrock: The dependency graph is only used to satisfy the constraints, if satisfying them all is possible. There is no _order_ needed, just the aggregate set of constraints that define the desired layout. It does require more thought then simpler layouts, but that's the reason it was designed as a powerful and flexible layout manager. I don't see anything that _needs_ to be documented here beyond the [attribute definitions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), and they're pretty self-explanatary in any case.

Comment: @corsair992 If you actually read the implementation of RelativeLayout, you will see that the dependency graph outputs a sorted list of the views for the set of horizontal constraints and vertical constraints separately, and resolve the layout for views based on this order. The difference in the behavior I stated in the question is exactly because of the difference in this resolution order, not anything else since semantically they should really be the same thing (i.e. box.right == next_box.left vs next_box.left == box.right).

Comment: @corsair992 You can see the source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java?av=f. Note specifically the sortChildren() method which was invoked in onMeasure(int, int).

Comment: @dementrock: Of course there is a dependency graph, and of course it outputs to a sorted list. How else are the constraints to be resolved logically, or determined to be unresolvable? The sematics of the two examples are quite different given the view dimensions defined - the left-side view's right resolves to 0, and the right-side view's left resolves to width - 60dip, which is a value greater than 0.

Comment: @corsair992 Take iOS AutoLayout or GSS (http://gridstylesheets.org/guides/ccss/), for example. Both of these use Cassowary algorithm to solve the set of constraints, which doesn't require the extra mindset of the constraints order.

Comment: @dementrock: I am not familiar with any of these things, but from reading the CCSS guide, I see that there are no view-only dependencies, and conflicts are resolved by using weights or in an undefined manner. I thought it was obvious that the rules would be observed per view, and wouldn't have any effect on any other view, except inasmuch as defined in their rules (that is the pattern everywhere in Android layouts). However, seeing these alternatives, I agree that this fact should perhaps be documented for `RelativeLayout`. You can open an issue on the bug tracker for this if you wish.

Comment: For me, I think the biggest giveaway that there was a dependency graph at play is that the designer will complain about circular dependency. i.e. you can't specify both layout_toRightOf="@+id/box" and layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_box" even though it makes sense logically.

Answer (score 1):

All this parameters defined in:
[android.widget.RelativeLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java/)

```
private void applyHorizontalSizeRules(LayoutParams childParams, int myWidth, int[] rules) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams anchorParams;

    // VALUE_NOT_SET indicates a "soft requirement" in that direction. For example:
    // left=10, right=VALUE_NOT_SET means the view must start at 10, but can go as far as it
    // wants to the right
    // left=VALUE_NOT_SET, right=10 means the view must end at 10, but can go as far as it
    // wants to the left
    // left=10, right=20 means the left and right ends are both fixed
    childParams.mLeft = VALUE_NOT_SET;
    childParams.mRight = VALUE_NOT_SET;

    anchorParams = getRelatedViewParams(rules, LEFT_OF);
    if (anchorParams != null) {
        childParams.mRight = anchorParams.mLeft - (anchorParams.leftMargin +
                childParams.rightMargin);
    } else if (childParams.alignWithParent && rules[LEFT_OF] != 0) {
        if (myWidth >= 0) {
            childParams.mRight = myWidth - mPaddingRight - childParams.rightMargin;
        }
    }

    anchorParams = getRelatedViewParams(rules, RIGHT_OF);
    if (anchorParams != null) {
        childParams.mLeft = anchorParams.mRight + (anchorParams.rightMargin +
                childParams.leftMargin);
    } else if (childParams.alignWithParent && rules[RIGHT_OF] != 0) {
        childParams.mLeft = mPaddingLeft + childParams.leftMargin;
    }

    anchorParams = getRelatedViewParams(rules, ALIGN_LEFT);
    if (anchorParams != null) {
        childParams.mLeft = anchorParams.mLeft + childParams.leftMargin;
    } else if (childParams.alignWithParent && rules[ALIGN_LEFT] != 0) {
        childParams.mLeft = mPaddingLeft + childParams.leftMargin;
    }

    anchorParams = getRelatedViewParams(rules, ALIGN_RIGHT);
    if (anchorParams != null) {
        childParams.mRight = anchorParams.mRight - childParams.rightMargin;
    } else if (childParams.alignWithParent && rules[ALIGN_RIGHT] != 0) {
        if (myWidth >= 0) {
            childParams.mRight = myWidth - mPaddingRight - childParams.rightMargin;
        }
    }

    if (0 != rules[ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT]) {
        childParams.mLeft = mPaddingLeft + childParams.leftMargin;
    }

    if (0 != rules[ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT]) {
        if (myWidth >= 0) {
            childParams.mRight = myWidth - mPaddingRight - childParams.rightMargin;
        }
    }
}
```

The view left and right edges ( childParams.mLeft,  childParams.mRight) calculations based on anchor view parameters (anchorParams). From this code childParams.mRight edge of the view defined by LEFT_OF (android:layout_toLeftOf) can be recalculated by ALIGN_RIGHT (android:layout_alignRight) or ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT (android:layout_alignParentRight). Here is explanation why 0-width red view become more than 0.

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_box"/>
```

Right edge of this view defined by LEFT_OF:

```
childParams.mRight = anchorParams.mLeft - (anchorParams.leftMargin +
                    childParams.rightMargin);
```

In this case anchor view is:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/next_box"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        />
```

the left edge of this view 60dp from the right side of the screen margings not defined => childParams.mRight = screen_width - 60dp

Left edge of this view defined by ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT:

```
childParams.mLeft = mPaddingLeft + childParams.leftMargin;
```

the left edge of this view left edge of anchor view is 0 because android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and margins not defined => childParams.mLeft = 0

the same calculation can be done for the second example:
childParams.mRight = screen_width
childParams.mLeft = 0